# Django queryset custom order with some objects on specified positions

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey('Site')
    published_at = models.DateTimeField(_('Published at'))
    promoted = models.BooleanField(_('Promoted'))
    position = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        _('Position'),
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    valid_from = models.DateTimeField(_('Valid from'))
    valid_to = models.DateTimeField(_('Valid to'))
    // (...)
```

I want to get the queryset with a specified position of some objects in specified time range. The rest of them should be ordered by `published` date.

The way I do it now works but it is slow and not efficient, which is a problem because I want to use it on the homepage.

```
def get_articles_list(site):
    articles = Article.objects.filter(
        site=site,
        published_at__lte=now(),
    ).order_by(
        '-published_at',
    )

    promoted_articles = Article.objects.filter(
        site=site,
        promoted=True,
        valid_from__lte=now(),
        valid_to__gte=now(),  
        position__isull=False,
    )

    // create a list with no promoted articles on it (to avoid duplicates)
    articles_list = list(articles.exclude(id__in=promoted_articles))

    // put promoted articles on the specific positions of the list
    if promoted_articles:
        for promoted in promoted_articles:
            articles_list.insert(promoted.position - 1, promoted)
    return articles_list
```

Is there a way to optimize the process?

**UPDATE**

For example I have five `Article` objects:

```
article_1
    site: 1
    published_at: 2018-04-01
    promoted: True
    position: 4
    valid_from: 2018-04-01
    valid_to: <tomorrow>
article_2
    site: 1
    published_at: 2018-04-02 
    promoted: False
    position: -
    valid_from: -
    valid_to: -
article_3
    site: 1
    published_at: 2018-04-03 
    promoted: False
    position: -
    valid_from: -
    valid_to: -
article_4
    site: 1
    published_at: 2018-04-04 
    promoted: False
    position: -
    valid_from: -
    valid_to: -
article_5
    site: 1
    published_at: 2018-04-05
    promoted: True
    position: 2
    valid_from: 2018-04-05
    valid_to: <tomorrow>
```

The order I want to achieve is:
`[article_4, article_5, article_3, article_1, article_2]`

Comment: Do You want to return queryset or list?

Comment: @DanielMiliński I would prefer to get a queryset.

Comment: After reading the question 3 times I still don't get what are the requirements. Why should `article_4` be the first and `article_2` last? What are the ordering criteria?

Comment: @cezar the articles that are `promoted` also have their `positions` granted. The `position` is the most important ordering criteria for me, that's why the `article_5` is on the 2nd position and `article_1` is on the 4th position of the list. After putting them on their positions we have the list: `[<position_1> , article_5, <position_3>, article_1, <position_5>]`. Now I want to "fill" the empty places with the rest of articles, sorted by `published_at` date. The `article_4` is the newest one, that's why it got 1st position, etc.

Comment: Your explanation makes no sense to me. `article5` is newer than `article4` (5th of April vs 4th of April). `article5` has position 2, `article4` has empty value (NULL) for position. Based on which criteria should `article4` be the first one?

Comment: @cezar, look at the comment above. The main criteria is the `position` value. This is the position (ordering number) of the object on the list/queryset. This means that `article_5` **must** be on the 2nd position (yeah, maybe it's the newest one but it has `position: 2` so it must "stick" to the position 2) and the `article_1` is on the 4th position of the list/queryset. The other objects (`article_2`, `article_3`, `article_4`) are just put in `published_at` date order on the rest of the list/queryset places. I know, I am not the best in making explanation but does it seem a bit cleaner now?

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand it. There is a flaw in your code that caused the misleading. The field `position` needs the attribute `unique=True`. Otherwise it would be possible to have mutliple articles with the same position, which would defeat the purpose.

Comment: Yeah, but its uniqueness depends also from the `site`, `valid_from` and `valid_to` fields. I wrote the custom validation method for it in my original code so this is already handled.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to add some middleware method that calculates the weight of each of the entry based on some custom logic - you need to define what params will make entries more promoted at the front of the list, and which are neutral.

I think this is how (more or less) search services like Algolia work (or just part of their features), where you can define what sort of 'score' multipliers have some of the params from your database.

(sorry for no actual Python code, but I don't use it on a daily basis - just wanted to help on general solution concept)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q


filters = Q(published_at_lte=now(), promoted=False)
filters.add(
    Q(promoted=True,
      valid_from__lte=now(),
      valid_to__gte=now(),  
      position__isnull=False),
    Q.OR
)

articles = (
    Article.objects
    .filter(site=site)
    .filter(filters)
    .order_by(
        '-promoted',
        'position',
        '-published_at'
    )
)
```

Comment: It's not what I want to achieve. Please, check out the example I just added to my question.

Answer (score 0):

First get the `promoted`, then order them in descending `published_at`.

```
Article.objects.filter(site=site).order_by('promoted', 'position', '-published_at')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#order-by

Comment: I've just added the example to my question. Please, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Postgresql you can try something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Case, When
    
queryset.order_by(
        Case(
            *[When(pk=item, then=index) for index, item in enumerate(ordered_ids)],
            default=len(ordered_ids) + 1,
        ),
        '-published_at',
    )
```